# How to create web services in JSP?

Tags: web-services, jsp

How to create web services in JSP?

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about hand-rolling XML responses with JSP: **Don't do it.**

There are specialized libraries for creating web services that take care of the various wire protocols, XML-based and otherwise. They save you a lot of time and trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You don't create webservices in jsp. JSP is a view technology, which allows you to control your pages showing logic.

About webservices, read [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create SOAP web services in Java you could use [Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html). JSP are simply a templating engine and cannot be used to create web services.